# how to change domain name in dotnetnuke?

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-6

i install dotnetnuke6 in local and set Alias name in iis to testdomain
after upload on host, all image in htmleditor module not display!
image url is testdomain/images/a.png (mistake)

is correctly url must
 /images/a.png (correctly) or  mydomain/images/a.png (correctly)

how to change image url

Answer (score 0):

Check out the HTML Editor Configuration settings under the HOST menu, you can control whether the editor uses relative or absolute URLs.

For existing HTML content stored in the database, you will likely want to use a tool like Engage: F3 (it's free http://www.engagemodules.com/Products/Engage_F3.aspx) to search/replace the paths with relative paths instead of absolute.

Comment: i change HTML content stored in the database and in edit mode display image but in view mode dont show!  how to Check out the HTML Editor Configuration settings?

Comment: Did you make changes directly in the database? You may need to refresh the DNN cache after that.

Comment: i update table whit this query update htmltext set content=cast(replace (cast(content as nvarchar(max)),'oldaddress','newaddres') as ntext) ,but in view mode show oldaddress

Comment: As a Host/SuperUser under the Tools menu click on the Clear Cache option

Comment: i do clear cache, but in view mode dont show image  only show in edit mode

Comment: Are you using "approvals"? Meaning you have to "publish" changes?

Comment: i change only database on host